# Condition in object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a object:

```
child_el = {
          height: sub_height,
          top: sizes.top,
          color: if sizes.top == 1 ? 0 : 1,
          };
```

How I can correctly put condition in property color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
child_el = {
   height: sub_height,
   top: sizes.top,
   color: sizes.top === 1 ? 0 : 1,
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to remove the `if` from `color` property.

Check the below code :

```
child_el = {
   height: sub_height,
   top: sizes.top,
   color: sizes.top === 1 ? 0 : 1
};
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: == operator can create problems in this case, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript